# insert data in WordPress database as non-logged in user

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I created a custom post type called 'visitor'. and I have an input in the front end. when the user saves input, I want to grab that data and post it as 'title' in my 'visitor' post type.

in functions.php-

```
$secureInfo= array(
  'site_url' => get_site_url(),
  'nonce' => wp_create_nonce("wp_rest")
);

wp_localize_script( "main-js", "data", $secureInfo);
```

in main.js-

```
sendUserInfo(){
    var grabbingInfo = {
      "title" : this.alertBoxInput.val() //my targeted input
    }

    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", data.nonce);
      },
      url: data.site_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/visitor", //custom post type
      data: grabbingInfo,
      type: "POST",
      success: (res) => {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: (res) => {
        console.log("sorry");
        console.log(res);
      }
    });
}
```

however, this code works for logged in user and says unauthorized for public users. but I don't care if a user is logged in or not. any suggestion?

Comment: There is a basic problem with what you are trying to do. You are creating a post. But, in WordPress a post has an owner (i.e., post_author) and this owner must be logged in to create a post.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to have a pseudo post author to create posts of non logged in users. This will require overriding the WordPress REST API authentication to set the current user to the pseudo post author when receiving your REST request.